# Code does not work for all test cases of flattening a nested list

Tags: python

Write a function to flatten a list. The list contains other lists, strings, or ints.
A list such as the example given below is to be flattened:

```
[[1,'a',['cat'],2],[[[3]],'dog'],4,5]
```

to produce a flattened list:

```
[1,'a','cat',2,3,'dog',4,5] (order matters)
```

I wrote my code as follows and got the required flattened list above. However, I did not score full marks for the question as apparently my code did not work for other test cases. **The question did not show me any test cases.Thus I only know that my code works properly for the example given above** Could you think of any cases that can show that my code is not correct?

My thinking process: Look through every index element in input list 'aList' by using a for loop. If that element happens to be a str/int, then that element is already flattened and I'll add that into my output flattened list 'new' using append. However, if that index element is still a list, it has not yet be flattened, so I'll do a recursive call 'new.append(aList[n])' so that I now look within list of list ie. aList[0][0] etc. until I find an element that is not a list.

```
new = []
def flatten(aList):


    for n in range(len(aList)):
        if type(aList[n]) == type([]):
                
                flatten(aList[n])
        else:
            new.append(aList[n])
    
    return new
```

**Here, I found a code online that gets me the full marks for the question.**

```
def flatten(aList):
    new = []
    for i in aList:
        if type(i) == type([]):
            new.extend(flatten(i))
            
        else:
            new.append(i)
            
    return new
```

It is very similar to my code, with the only difference in the way it calls the recursive function to flatten any nested lists. I directly call my function 'flatten(aList[n])' while the sample answer used 'new.extend(flatten(i)). However, I could not see why my code does not work for all cases. Also, how is using extend going to solve the problem?

Comment: By declaring `new = []` outside of the function, it will fail to flatten a second array. So I guess by having 2 test your function fails? Try moving it into the function

Comment: Run your code twice on the same list and print the output: `[1, 'a', 'cat', 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 1, 'a', 'cat', 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5]`. simply moving it into the function wont work either.

Comment: `extend` is exactly build to insert all elements of an iterable into the list it is executed with - so its better to use then appending single elements from a computational standpoint

Comment: See [how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) or [flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists) for more solutions on how to do this

Comment: If it's a multi test-case problem, you need to reset new after each call to 'flatten' method.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a multi test-case problem, you need to reset new after each call to 'flatten' method.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is correct. Your test cases are probably failing because of the `new` variable declared outside of the `flatten` function. This causes the result of the function to be extended to the `new` list that already contains results from previous function calls. Pass the list as parameter for a recursive solution:

```
def flatten(aList, new=None):
   if new == None: new = []
    for n in range(len(aList)):
        if type(aList[n]) == type([]):
                
                flatten(aList[n], new)
        else:
            new.append(aList[n])
    
    return new
```

What's important here that notice how I have used the default value of the argument `new` as `None` and then assigned it inside the function if it is `None`, rather than just:    `def flatten(aList, new=[]):`. Never do this–use a mutable datatype like list as a default argument as it will only be evaluated once and this instance will be reused everytime the function is called rather than creating a fresh empty list. Check [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) out for more details.

If you want better performance, try using two functions to optimize the `if` away:

```
flatten = lambda aList: flatten_aux(aList, [])

def flatten_aux(aList, new):
    for n in range(len(aList)):
        if type(aList[n]) == type([]):
                
                flatten(aList[n], new)
        else:
            new.append(aList[n])
    
    return new
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question, but rather an alternative way to solve the problem using generators (I would post this as a comment, but comments don't format multi-line code, to the best of my knowledge):

```py
def flat_gen(nd_list):
    if type(nd_list) is list:
        for i in nd_list:
            yield from flat_gen(i)
    else:
        yield nd_list

def flatten(nd_list):
    return list(flat_gen(nd_list))

nd_list = [[1,'a',['cat'],2],[[[3]],'dog'],4,5]
flat_list = flatten(nd_list)
print(flat_list)
answer = [1,'a','cat',2,3,'dog',4,5]
print(flat_list == answer)
```

Output:

```
[1, 'a', 'cat', 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5]
True
```